# Ui-router html5mode not loading templates

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

The app works fine without adding html5Mode(true), but when I add that line (and set the base href) I just get a blank page returned. All asset files are loaded correctly. Looking a bit deeper, I can see that it's not loading the templates when html5Mode(true) is set.

I'm defining the routes like this:

```
angular
        .module('app')
        .config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function appRouter($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
            $stateProvider

                .state('app', {

                    abstract: true,
                    url: '',
                    templateUrl: 'modules/app/index.html'

                })

                .state('app.view1', {

                    url: '',
                    templateUrl: 'modules/view1/index.html',
                    controller: 'View1Controller'

                })

                .state('app.view2', {

                    url: '',
                    templateUrl: 'modules/view2/index.html',
                    controller: 'View2Controller'

                });

        }]);
```

The base tag is like this:

```
<base href="/app/index.html" />
```

And the folder structure is like this:

```
app --> all files required to run app
    css --> css assets
    img --> img
    modules --> all functionality is a module
        app --> main app module. Instantiates app, loads modules, and handles routing
            app.controller.js --> app controller logic
            app.module.js --> app module declaration
            app.router.js --> all app routing
            index.html -->
        view1
            view1.controller.js --> view1 controller logic
            view1.module.js --> view1 module declaration
            index.html --> view1 html
        view2
            view2.controller.js --> view2 controller logic
            view2.module.js --> view2 module declaration
            index.html --> view2 html
    index.html --> main entry point
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current settings is looking for 'www.example.com/app/modules/app/index.html'. Trying changing the base tag as below:

If your site is www.example.com/index.html , then `<base href="/" />`

If your site is www.example.com/other/index.html, then `<base href="/other/" />`

Source: [Angular.js base tag setting troubleshooting](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase)

Also, double check the URL's are resolving correctly by using chrome dev tools, Network tab, and then try loading the state to see if the get request for the template succeeds/is to the right URL.

Lastly, since I believe you are using `ui-router`, there's a troubleshooting/description for the base tag as well : [ui-router docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#user-content-decision-tree)

Comment: The app is on my development server and I'm visiting it by going to `localhost:8000/app/`. I can see in the Chrome dev tools that all the relevant assets (including javascript) are being loaded correctly.

Comment: I recreated your problem in a plunker, and I don't know exactly why yet, but if you change the `url` in the parent 'app' state from `''` to `'/'`, the child views show up for me. Also, console logging `$state` in the parent app loads "app.view1" without html5mode by default, but "app.view2" with html5mode as default.